# Add current sdkconfig defines to Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, esp32, kconfig

I work with ESP32 IDF4.2 in Visual Studio Code. I have lots of configurations and options set by the precompiler through the 'menuconfig' tool that generates a sdkconfig in /proyectx/build/

It would be quite useful to have that file taken by the program so I could see the actual code that is being compiled; but I cannot find a way to do so.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the official vscode extension.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=espressif.esp-idf-extension